# updating scala jar (lang:scala-library:jar:2.7.7) is giving exception

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to update org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.7.7 ,  from version 2.7.7 to 2.10.7 , in my project it is throwing exception 
while starting server -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor126.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585)
```

How to approach to solve this problem?

Please let me know if any other detail is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just update the Scala runtime jar like this: any dependencies of your application which are written in Scala will need to be updated to a 2.10-compatible version and Scala code of your application will need to be recompiled with Scala 2.10 as well.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Romanov . this jar is dependent on kestrel jar (which i got from dependency tree ) . i cant update kestrel. so that i excluded scala from there and added it outside.like individual dependency

Comment: How to check compatibility ?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/twitter-archive/kestrel, the last version worked on Scala 2.9. So you'll probably need to build and test it for 2.10 yourself.